# How I can use ajax call to retrieve large number of records on chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have a jsp page where I am making an ajax call to retrieve records from the db.
My problem is that when the number of records retrieved is greater than 10000 record,the ajax call will never execute the call back.This problem occurs only on chrome,but on FireFox and IE 11 it is working.
Note that there is no exception or error thrown in the java side or on the browser.
Another thing is that if the number of records is less than 10000 it is working fine.
Here is the ajax call I am using:

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: d.url+'?actionName='+d.actionName,
              async:bAsync,
              contentType :'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
              data:d.lastQuery,
              success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                  window.top.jsdopost.getHTTPResponse(d,xhr);
              },
              error:function(req, status, e ){
                jsdopost.bProcessingRequest=false;
                jsdopost.throwError("getData()",e.message,d);
                return;     
              }
        });
```

Comment: No there is no console error

Comment: use some plugins to load large sets of data like [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: what is "top.jsdopost.getHTTPResponse(d,xhr);" doing?

Comment: It will process the response bases on its status:if(xh.status == 200),xh.status==403,xh.status==400 || xh.status==500 or it will throw an exception.

Comment: But we are not entering in it,I am sure about that

Comment: Did you hear about PostMan ? Can call your http with it and show us your running time?

Comment: It is taking about 20s

Comment: I think it is not about size it's about time. Can you try these code with less results. 10 sec...